# Leaflet marker clustering

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openlayers, gis

I am following closely the example of https://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet while adding more useful functions. Everything works out of the box except the additional clustering of marker using the plugin from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster. I thought to replace the line

```
var plotmark = new L.Marker(plotll);
```

with

```
var plotmark = new L.MarkerClusterGroup(plotll);
```

while this triggers an error in leaflet.js. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) ?

You should have

```
var group = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
group.addLayer(new L.Marker(plot11));
... Add more layers ...
map.addLayer(group);
```

Comment: Thank so much FranceImage - I believe we are nearly there. Added the code above starting at line #219 in https://wjst.de/images/gps/index.php but still to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer of FranceImage shows the correct syntax, the problem was caused by an incompatibility between the current markercluster and leaflet version. Switching back to Leaflet 0.7.3 (May 2014) solved it.